# How do I make grape wine at 60%ABV, that tastes good?

Tags: wine, ginger, alcohol

Its my first time. I want to make some wine. Please tell me how I increase my wines alcohol percentage around 60%.

- Is it possible, Does anyone know the process?
- How much yeast, should I use in the grape juice?
- I have baking yeast and I can’t collect Brewer’s yeast, can I convert baking yeast to brewer’s yeast?
- Can I add liquid ginger in grapes juice?
- How do I know if my wine is unfit for drinking?

Comment: Why the downvotes on this question? Just because its infeasible to do what is being asked doesn't make it a bad question, in my opinion.

Answer (score 2):

Well, theoretically you can add any kind of yeast to any kind of grape extract and, provided conditions are sanitary, you don't get an infection, and you give it enough time to ferment, you will have a wine of some sort. Unfortunately, it probably won't be very good. In fact, it will probably be horrible.

To make drinkable wine will require proper juice, and the use of proper strains of a wine yeast (usually *Saccharomyces cerevisiae*). I would recommend you read the overview and history of [Winemaking on Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Winemaking) to get an understanding of the basic process, then ask more specific questions here.

In addition, consider visiting your local homebrew supply store and talking with the people there. They will be able to answer any questions you may have, and sell you the equipment you need to successfully make good wine.

In order to get an alcohol percentage of 60%... well, it probably wouldn't be considered wine any more. This would either require distillation into a brandy with a still, or perhaps freeze distillation. Please check with your local laws as distillation may not be legal where you live.

Answer (score 2):

To Exactly answer your questions:

Is it possible, Does anyone know the process?

Yes, you would have to ferment some wine then add a very high ABV% of Alcohol, acquired, paid or distilled by another means.
Example ratio:
300ml of 10% wine + 700ml of 80% spirit = 59%ABV

How much yeast, should I use in the grape juice?

Go for 1 tsp per gallon(4.5L).

can I convert baking yeast to brewer’s yeast?

No they are different strains, but bakers yeast will make alcohol.

Can I add liquid ginger in grapes juice?

Yes, you are drinking it, you add whatever you like.

How do I know if my wine is unfit for drinking?

Typically is smells bad, tastes bad or has a visible infection growing in it. I believe (please correct me guys) typically there is nothing harmful to humans that can grow in brewed beverages, but will taste terrible.

Please look around, including this site grow your knowledge, and feel free to ask more questions. If 60% ABV is your goal, I would direct you to [HomeDistillers](http://wiki.homedistiller.org/Main_Page) for achieving this, (please forgive me homeDistillers!)

I downvoted your question, because I believe  you are missing some huge fundamentals, require some online reading and I don't believe you question is improving question catalogue. Also this approach will lead to some terrible tasting drink.

Comment: I agree with most of the answer, but baking yeast and beer yeast are genetically the same.

Comment: I'll make amendments.

Comment: Baker's Yeast and Brewing yeasts (Ale) are not genetically the same, they are very similar, but different strains of S.cerevisiae can have subtly distinct genomes and more varied epigenetics. Bakers yeast and Lager yeast (Saccharomyces pastorianus) are highly distinct.

Answer (score 1):

Buy some wine yeast - don't use bread yeast - wine yeast is more alcohol tolerant and will give you the best chance of producing something like wine. But even so, nowhere near 60% - most yeasts stop around 14-18 percent abv.

Answer (score 1):

Getting ABV at that level is possible through distillation process. Although it won't be classified as wine anymore if the ABV is 60%.

[Here](http://winemaking.jackkeller.net/basics.asp) you go to get started making wine. You can know how much yeast should be used at that tutorial as well.

We can make wine using either brewer or baking yeast and it's drinkable, but you won't get optimal result if using baking yeast. Brewer yeast has been produced to get optimal result in wine making through many researches. Baking yeast can cause off-flavour to your wine.

There are some recipes using ginger. Check [this](http://winemaking.jackkeller.net/recipes.asp) out.